# Can we easily link to an interactive data visualization rather than a simple picture of it?

Tags: support

I just asked a question where I wanted to include the interactive graphic embedded in [this article](http://blogs.ft.com/ftdata/2013/09/23/how-the-ipccs-projections-match-up/) on a Financial Times blog.

The original dataviz is an interactive Tableau Public visualization.

I couldn't find an easy way to either copy a static picture or link directly to the original source. Is this possible on stackexchange? How would I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The article you linked is behind paywall so I cannot look at it.

However, the problem is fundamentally that there is no data exchange standard for interactive plots of this kind. There are file formats for static graphics (e.g. PNG, JPEG) and moving stuff (GIF, AVI …), and even to some extent for interactive graphics (SWF aka. Flash, or Java Applets). But most newfangled interactive graphics don’t use Flash any more (for very good technical reasons). Instead, they use scripts that are tightly integrated into the surrounding website and cannot be extracted in an automated, portable fashion.

So, **no dice**.

Come back in three years, with a bit of luck the situation will look differently then, as people have agreed on some common data exchange standard to use. There are already some ideas out there – for instance, Facebook provides an API to embed comments into pages, Twitter allows embedding tweets and timelines, Trello also provides a neat widget – but none of these use one standardised format, they all use their own protocol.

Comment: I may have been too hasty in testing links: the interactive chart is here http://public.tableausoftware.com/shared/RXQ2CD99K?:display_count=no and it seems to offer some alternatives to linking.

Comment: @matt_black Not bad. The problem with this is that, in order to link this, Stack Overflow would essentially have to embed an (untrusted) third-party JavaScript. There are some restrictions as to what this can do, but those are few – essentially, it’s a huge security hole so the only way Stack Exchange could conceivably allow this is by manually maintaining a whitelist of allowed (“trusted”) sources (that’s not impossible though).

Answer (score 0):

> I couldn't find an easy way to either copy a static picture or link directly to the original source.

To copy a static picture you can take a [screenshot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screenshot), save the screenshot as an image file on your computer, and then use that image file in the usual way.